# Issue while adding picasso and glide library dependancy

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

Actually I want to add Picasso or Glide library in my application but whenever I use dependency of them I'm getting errors (Please check below screen for more details) I am using Android Studio 3.0.1
I tried almost all solution like instant run unchecked, offline update unchecked, add multidexed on change SDK version higher 27.0.1
Please suggest

here is my build.gradle for Piasso:
[image: here is my build.gradle for Piasso]

here is the error for Picasso library:
[image: here is the error for Picasso library]

here is my build.gradle for Glide:
[image: here is my build.gradle for Glide]

here is my error for Glide:
[image: here is my error for Glide]

error for glide library is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

```
style.xml



     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>

manifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.neuralit.developer.myapplicationtest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: add you app level and project level gradle file

Comment: Read the guidelines of stack overflow. Don't put the link . Put the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and use this gradle for Glide

```
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Keep the **`compileSdkVersion`** to 26

Comment: bro your answer works. Thanks. but i didn't understand why new dependency not working same.

Comment: i am glad it worked, actually it i had the same issue , after doing research came to know , there is issue in glide gradle version above 4.0

Comment: Please mark my answer just below the downvote icon and up vote it so others can refer it :), Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

There a different issues:

#1 You must add both Glide and Picasso in the same gradle file (the one in the 'app' folder).
Remove the one in `app\src\androidTest\java`

**EDIT**

#2 Glide 4 doesn't work with the support lib 26.

- You need to upgrade to 27 (latest version is [27.1.1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions))
- You need to upgrade the targetSdkVersion to 27
- You need to upgrade to compileSDKversion to 27

[See Glide documentaiton for more info](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html)

**EDIT 2**

Actually you can still use v26 if you really want to (see the doc above, but it's not recommended). But in any case you shouldn't use the beta version as the 26 has been released for a while. So if you want to keep the 26 you should use 26.0.2 which has bug fixes. (`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'`)

#3 According to the last screenshot you've provided, you probably have another issue. But fix the first one and come back to us if the problem still appears.

But as Glide and Picasso are supposed to do the same thing, why do you want to use both?

Comment: In the links you've provided, you're using 2 gradles files. One is located in `\app` and the other one in `\app\src\androidTest\java`. You don't need the second one and you **must** remove it. You must add all your dependencies in the first one

Comment: I updated as you said now getting same error as below: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Please add your Manifest and styles.xml files to the question

Comment: Do you still have the issue as you've accepted the other answer (means your problem is solved)?